# Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare data frame in each csv files in a folder. I want to make a code that detects if (cas>vref_new) or (vref>cas), it would give a result that the file is unstabilized approach. Below is the code.

```
os.chdir("D:\TUGAS\TA\TUYS\Data TA dari Garuda\File Yut dan Dimas\SelesaiTA")
dflist=pd.DataFrame()
for file in  os.listdir("D:\TUGAS\TA\TUYS\Data TA dari Garuda\File Yut dan Dimas\SelesaiTA"):

    df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = [0,1,3,4])
    df.columns = [column.replace(" ","_") for column in df.columns]
    df.columns = [column.replace("/","_") for column in df.columns]
    dff = df[(df.ALTITUDE_ABOVE_FIELD_ELEV <= 500) & (df.DISTANCE_TO_THRESHOLD < 5) & (df.LANDING_GEAR_STATUS != "FULL_GRD")]
    cas = dff.iloc[:,10:11].astype('float64').reset_index(drop=True)
    vref = dff.iloc[:,132:133].astype('float64').reset_index(drop=True)
    vref_new = vref+20
    if ((cas>vref_new) or (vref>cas)):
      print('Unstabilized Approach%s ' %file)
```

I have already checked the cas and vref dataframe is float and still got ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects. Any help would be appreciated

The data frame looks like this for cas

```
    COMPUTED_AIR_SPEED 
0   148.0
1   147.5
2   148.5
3   149.3
4   148.5
5   148.3
6   149.0
7   148.0
8   148.0
9   148.0
10  147.0
11  146.0
12  147.3
13  148.8
14  148.0
15  147.5
16  146.5
17  148.5
18  147.5
19  148.3
```

The data frame looks like this for vref

```
    VREF_AT_LANDING
0   142.0
1   142.0
2   142.0
3   142.0
4   142.0
5   142.0
6   142.0
7   142.0
8   142.0
9   142.0
10  142.0
11  142.0
12  142.0
13  142.0
14  142.0
15  142.0
16  142.0
17  142.0
18  142.0
19  142.0
```

Comment: What do the DataFrames actually look like?

Comment: I already edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of issues here. The first, as the error says, is that you can only compare identically labeled DataFrames. Yours are not. One has a single column labelled `"COMPUTED_AIR_SPEED"` and the other has a single column labelled `"VREF_AT_LANDING"`. That right there is what throws the error. If you give the columns the same label and distinguish between the two datasets by the name you give to the DataFrame's variable, you won't get this error.

When you fix that, you'll find another error. Those expressions do not resolve to a single Boolean value of `True` or `False`. It returns a Series that has `True` or `False` for each row depending on which DataFrame had a greater value at that index. So the next step is to reduce the value using `.any()` or `.all()`.

If you want it to send the "unstabilized approach" result to the file if ANY of the rows are greater in one DataFrame than another, use `.any()` if you need all of them to be greater before you send the result, use `.all()`.

Finally, the previous step will give you a Series with a single Boolean value instead of a Boolean. Just tack `.any()` on at the end again to get the Boolean:

```
if ((cas>vref_new).any().any() or (vref>cas)).any().any():
    ....
```